# Why is my Javascript password validation criteria not updating in realtime?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to create a password validation form and it works fairly well. However, the ticks for each validation criteria i.e. use of uppercase, lowercase and numeric characttmlers do not update as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let first,
    len = document.getElementById("len"),
    upr = document.getElementById("upr"),
    lwr = document.getElementById("lwr"),
    spc = document.getElementById("spc"),
    num = document.getElementById("num"),
    match_ = document.getElementById("match"),
    submit = document.querySelector("input[type=submit]");
  submit.classList.add("disabled");

  for (let [index, i] of document.querySelectorAll("input[type=password]").entries()) {
    i.addEventListener("focus", function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("validate")[index].style.display = "block";
    });
    i.addEventListener("blur", function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("validate")[index].style.display = "none";
    });
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        first = i;
        i.addEventListener("input", function() {
          if (this.value.length >= 8) {
            len.setAttribute("icon", "mdi:tick-circle");
          } else {
            len.setAttribute("icon", "gridicons:cross-circle");
            if (!submit.classList.contains("disabled")) submit.classList.add("disabled");
            return false;
          }
          if (this.value.match(/[a-z]/g)) {
            lwr.setAttribute("icon", "mdi:tick-circle");
          } else {
            lwr.setAttribute("icon", "gridicons:cross-circle");
            if (!submit.classList.contains("disabled")) submit.classList.add("disabled");
            return false;
          }
          if (this.value.match(/[A-Z]/g)) {
            upr.setAttribute("icon", "mdi:tick-circle");
          } else {
            upr.setAttribute("icon", "gridicons:cross-circle");
            if (!submit.classList.contains("disabled")) submit.classList.add("disabled");
            return false;
          }
          if (this.value.match(/[!@#$%^&*.]/g)) {
            spc.setAttribute("icon", "mdi:tick-circle");
          } else {
            spc.setAttribute("icon", "gridicons:cross-circle");
            if (!submit.classList.contains("disabled")) submit.classList.add("disabled");
            return false;
          }
          if (this.value.match(/[0-9]/g)) {
            num.setAttribute("icon", "mdi:tick-circle");
          } else {
            num.setAttribute("icon", "gridicons:cross-circle");
            if (!submit.classList.contains("disabled")) submit.classList.add("disabled");
            return false;
          }
        });
        break;
      case 1:
        i.addEventListener("input", function() {
          if (first.value == this.value) {
            match_.setAttribute("icon", "mdi:tick-circle");
          } else {
            match_.setAttribute("icon", "gridicons:cross-circle");
            if (!submit.classList.contains("disabled")) submit.classList.add("disabled");
            return false;
          }
          submit.classList.remove("disabled");
        });
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.validate {
    display: none;
}

iconify-icon[icon="mdi:tick-circle"] {
    color: green;
}

iconify-icon[icon="gridicons:cross-circle"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/iconify-icon/1.0.2/iconify-icon.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="trial4.html">
    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
      <label class="form-label">Password:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="validate">
      <p>
        <iconify-icon icon="gridicons:cross-circle" id="len"></iconify-icon>
        Password length = 8
      </p>
      <p>
        <iconify-icon icon="gridicons:cross-circle" id="upr"></iconify-icon>
        Contains at least one uppercase letter
      </p>
      <p>
        <iconify-icon icon="gridicons:cross-circle" id="lwr"></iconify-icon>
        Contains at least one lowercase letter
      </p>
      <p>
        <iconify-icon icon="gridicons:cross-circle" id="spc"></iconify-icon>
        Contains at least one special character (!@#$%^&*).
      </p>
      <p>
        <iconify-icon icon="gridicons:cross-circle" id="num"></iconify-icon>
        Contains at least one numeric character
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
      <label class="form-label">Confirm Password:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" required="required">
    </div>
    <div class="validate">
      <p>
        <iconify-icon icon="gridicons:cross-circle" id="match"></iconify-icon>
        Must match password
      </p>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

On entering an uppercase letter, the tick does not update immediately and neither do other criteria such as lowercase, numeric and special characters (!@#$%^&*). How can I solve this? Suggestions such as code improvements are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are your `else` block in which you have `return false` so the first condition beeing `false` will result in the follow up conditions not to be checked.

You could do something like:

```
    i.addEventListener("input", function() {
          // have a variable that holds the valid state
          let isValid = true
      
          if (this.value.length >= 8) {
            len.setAttribute("icon", "mdi:tick-circle");
          } else {
            len.setAttribute("icon", "gridicons:cross-circle");
            if (!submit.classList.contains("disabled")) submit.classList.add("disabled");

            // set the valid state to false if the condition was not met
            isValid = false
          }
          if (this.value.match(/[a-z]/g)) {
            lwr.setAttribute("icon", "mdi:tick-circle");
          } else {
            lwr.setAttribute("icon", "gridicons:cross-circle");
            if (!submit.classList.contains("disabled")) submit.classList.add("disabled");

            // set the valid state to false if the condition was not met
            isValid = false
          }
          //....
          
          return isValid
       })
```

Comment: What of the confirm password input? I want it such that if I edit the first input the second input's validation is performed immediately to prevent mismatching passwords.